# How do I exclude white spaces from the count?

Tags: java

I have to keep count of how many letters (characters) are in file "test.txt". I got that down, but it includes the spaces as well, which I don't want to include. Any suggestions on how to do so? Thanks so much.

```
import java.io.*;
class EnglishAnalysis
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            int count = 0;
            String lineCharacters [];
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                 lineCharacters = line.split("");
                 for (int i = 0; i < lineCharacters.length; i++)
                 {
                     count ++;
                     line = br.readLine();
                 }
                 System.out.println(count);
             }
             br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character class has an "isWhiteSpace()" method

java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(char ch)

```
while (line != null)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
      if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
         count ++;
      line = br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(count);
  }
```

Comment: lineCharacters is an aray of Strings. A String can't be passed to Character.isWhitespace(). Don't split a string to get all its chars. Just use charAt().

Comment: I think you've got the right idea here, but your `line = br.readLine();` is in the wrong place.  You're going to try to read a new line after processing the first character in the prior line.  You want to move that line outside the **for loop**.  When you do, I think our answers are equivalent. - oh...you want to move the `println` outside the **while loop** too unless you want to print an updated count after every line is processed.

Answer (score 2):

Or (Java 8+) you can do this very easily with the `lines()` and `chars()` methods:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
long count = br.lines().flatMapToInt(e -> e.codePoints()).filter(e -> !Character.isWhiteSpace(e)).count();
```

Which will take a `Stream<String>` of the lines of the file, flat map them to the chars with `String::codePoints`, filter out any whitespace, and then count the elements

Comment: OP asked to not count "white spaces", not just spaces, so use `filter(e -> !   Character.isWhitespace(e))` and use [`codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) instead of `chars()`.

Comment: Instead of [`BufferedReader.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--), you might want to use [`Files.lines(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand what good the split does.  I'd do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/tmp/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int count = 0;
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
                    count++;
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(count);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Specifically, I see no need to modify the input at all, by calling split, making extra copies, doing find/replace, etc.  That all just takes extra time and space.

And actually, I don't see any reason to bother processing the file in lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("/tmp/test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            int c = br.read();
            if (c < 0)
                break;
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(c))
                count++;
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(count);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Using a BufferedReader in and of itself gives you the efficiency of not reading the file character by character.  So you save an extra copy of each line by doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add the number of characters for each line after you have cleaned it from all spaces:

```
    while (line != null) {
        count += line.replaceAll("\\s+", "").length();
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: OP asked to not count "white spaces", not just spaces, so use `replace("\\s", "")`, or `replace("\\p{javaWhitespace}", "")` for full unicode support.

Answer (score 0):

Why not removing whitespaces from the string, before doing the split and count?

One way of doing it, using regular expressions:

```
while (line != null)
{
  line.replaceAll("\\s+","");
  lineCharacters = line.split("");
  ...
}
```